# android : AutoCompleteTextView linked to huge table

Tags: android, sqlite, autocompletetextview

I want to link AutoCompleteTextView to a huge (1.5 million records) table in SQLite

I am new to android programming, but this does not ok to me to link this big table to AutoCompleteTextView.

is this approach ok?
is there any other way I can choose top 10 records while user typing on the AutoCompleteTextView.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `AutoCmpeleteTextview` in my application where i am loading data from cursor.
you can use same approach to do so.(i am not sure its best or not but its working perfect for me.)
so for solution you can use thread to load that data. 
it will load data while user is typing.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    readData();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }

        }).start();
```